# MultiDataTrigger is firing if only one condition is met

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, datatrigger, multidatatrigger

in my UserControl I have three ComboBoxes which all have to be selected before the save button is enabled. I defined a MultiDataTrigger with Bindings to my ViewModel Properties which are set to null initially. So when the control is loaded the button is disabled as expected but as soon as one of the ComboBoxes is selected the button will be enabled. As I understood all conditions of a MultiDataTrigger have to be met in order for it to fire?

Here's my Button Style:

```
        <Style x:Key="saveButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=CurrentSpeech.Room, Converter={StaticResource nullToBoolConverter}}" Value="true" />
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=CurrentSpeech.Speaker, Converter={StaticResource nullToBoolConverter}}" Value="true" />
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=CurrentSpeech.Track, Converter={StaticResource nullToBoolConverter}}" Value="true" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Button.IsEnabled" Value="False" />
            </MultiDataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

My ComboBoxes:

```
            <ComboBox Margin="3" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Rooms, Mode=OneWay}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CurrentSpeech.Room, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
            <ComboBox Margin="3" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Tracks, Mode=OneWay}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CurrentSpeech.Track, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="Title"/>
            <ComboBox Margin="3" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Speakers, Mode=OneWay}" 
                      SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CurrentSpeech.Speaker, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
```

My Button:

```
                <Button Style="{StaticResource saveButton}" Margin="3" Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="1" Command="{Binding Path=CurrentSpeech.SaveCommand}" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="Speichern"/>
```

And my Converter:

```
    [ValueConversion(typeof(object), typeof(bool))]
public class NullToBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool result = value == null ? true : false;
        if (parameter != null)
            return !result;
        return result;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Paxx

Comment: Did you try debugging? Did you check if the values in your converter are really null?

Comment: Hi Blachshma, I just checked. When the window is loaded the converter returns true for all 3 conditions. If I choose one of them the converter returns false. So it seems the converter is working correctly.

Comment: Oh, this wasn't the problem. It still isn't working correctly, only the converter is. As soon as one of the conditions is met the button will be enabled, which isn't what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trigger seems to work fine, it's just your logic that is not correct.

As it works now, the trigger will be activated when the `Room`, `Speaker` and `Track` properties are all null. That happens when the program starts, since nothing is selected in either of the `ComboBoxes`.

So all 3 conditions are met, and the trigger disables the `Button`.

When you then select something in the `Rooms` combobox, the first condition in the trigger is no longer met, since the `ValueConverter` now returns `false` for that binding, so the trigger is disabled and this causes the button to be enabled.

So to fix this issue, you should disable the `Button` initially, and only set it enabled in the trigger, when the converters return false for all bindings (when the 3 properties are NOT null).

```
<Style x:Key="saveButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Room, Converter={StaticResource nullToBoolConverter}}" Value="false" />
                <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Speaker, Converter={StaticResource nullToBoolConverter}}" Value="false" />
                <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Track, Converter={StaticResource nullToBoolConverter}}" Value="false" />
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Button.IsEnabled" Value="True" />
        </MultiDataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thank you, for your answer Peter. I tried that before posting, but if set the button to disabled it stays disabled no matter what I do. I kept it the way it was, in my initial post, because that's the only way it kinda works. But I understand now that it can't work this way.

Comment: Ah my bad ... I overlooked the line in your post where you set the IsEnabled Property in the style, I always tried to set it directly in the button definition. It works now, thank's a lot Peter!